# Scheme: Read a list inside a file an load it into a variable

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm a complete beginner with Scheme. I have to code a function that reads a file and load its content into a variable using `with-input-from-file` proc. The content of the file is a list, e.g., `(1 2 (3 4) abc r)`.

I don't even know how to begin. Someone could help me?

Comment: Are you aware of `read`? Are you allowed to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(define my-list (call-with-input-file "file-that-contains-list.txt" read))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works fine! But I had to use with-input-from-file proc, so I changed it for (define my-list (with-input-from-file "file-that-contains-list.txt" read))